# Why does this recursive vim macro stop?

Tags: macro

I saw an [example](https://medium.com/@jovica/the-power-of-recursive-macros-in-vim-1ecfa35c1183) of a recursive vim macro, and it stops, but I don't quite understand why.  My guess is that it stops because it can't find any more `:`, but I'm unsure if I am correct; does anyone know why it stops?

Macro contents:

```
i<Tab>'<Esc>f:C',<Esc>j^@a
```

Register `a` is first empties with `qaq` and then recorded into with `qa{...}q`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [repeat.txt](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%40):

> The register is executed like a mapping

and [map.txt](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map-error):

> Note that when an error is encountered (that causes an error message or beep)
>   the rest of the mapping is not executed.

So there's been some kind of error before reaching the `@a`.  The documentation doesn't give an exhaustive list of all the possible errors for each action, but the most likely options are:

- `f` didn't find a `:`
- `j` couldn't move down (because there were no more lines in the buffer)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what data you run it on. In the animated gif in the linked page, you're correct that it stops because the `f` command cannot find a colon.

If instead every line in the file from the cursor on downwards contained a colon, the macro would stop when the `j` command cannot move down, i.e. at the bottom of the file.